# Cant boot from USB drive. Cant access GRUB. No graphical interface

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, usb

I started an upgrade to 12.04 but stalled during install. Now, the system boots directly into command window where I must sign in. I tried creating a bootable USB (no CD drive installed) with unetbootin and Universal USB Installer, but the system do not boot to USB first - goes directly to hard drive. I tried accessing the grub menu with all suggested commands (ex holding shift, F1, Esc, F10, F12 etc etc etc) but none worked. How can I install the new version 12.04 LTS from USB? Is there any way to install from command line? Or how can I access GRUB settings from command?

Please please please help!

PS. I am not very familiar with Linux-type systems, so step-by-step guidance would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/384706/178596) help with booting? There is also a few step-by-step guides [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support). Look at the right hand side of the page.

Comment: Still having this problem? You haven't been around in a while and you haven't responded to the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your machine will boot first in its USB. You can do this by setting its Boot Priority/Sequence in BIOS.

1. Restart your machine
2. Press F2 or the key that will let you access the setup for BIOS
3. Under Boot Priority/Boot Sequence tab, make the USB as the first priority to boot
4. Then try restarting your machine again. It must now boot in your USB

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem is that none of the keys (like you suggested F2) let me access the GRUB / BIOS. Therefore I cannot set boot priority...Is there a way to access grub settings from command line window?