# How do I dual boot Ubuntu 13.10 on my Windows 8.1 Samsung NP35V5C-A01US laptop?

Tags: windows, 13.10

I made the partition for ubuntu in disc management, and I have also made the live usb. When i put the live usb into my laptop and boot up, windows just boots up normally instead of going to the live usb....
help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to select it to boot up - disable Secure Boot in BIOS *(like a hardware settings thing before Windows boots up)*, and allow booting from USB. There is a helpful guide [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-access-the-bios-on-a-windows-8-computer/).

[image: boot up]

Save your changes, and power off and on again - then select 'Boot Device Menu' or something similar, and then the USB or Disc entry under the manufacturer of the USB stick or disk drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows8 normal shut-down is not a complete shut-down but rather an "enhanced" form of hibernation (especially on new laptops, in order to facilitate faster boot times.) To perform a "proper" complete shut-down you have to keep the `shift` key pressed while shutting down windows. The next time you power-up the computer will obey the preferred boot device sequence (assuming you have made the desired modifications through the BIOS setup.)